# Joining another table in MySQL inflates count number

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have three tables in a MySQL database, and after joining two of them together, the `COUNT()` function in my query no longer works properly, and returns inflated numbers instead.

Please excuse my messy code as it is my first time using MySQL.
This is the query I have written which works:

```
SELECT 
    promo.ID,
    promo.Branch,
    promo.Promoter,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sales.brand = 'TEST' AND sales.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' AND promo.branch = sales.branch THEN 1 END) AS Actual, 
FROM sales.promo
    LEFT JOIN sales.sales ON promo.promoter = sales.promoter
GROUP BY promo.ID 
ORDER BY promo.ID ASC;
```

The `COUNT()` function here returns the correct number.

I have three tables: `promo`, `sales` and `model`.

What I wanted to do is expand it so that it could also filter the model details. The idea is that `using promo.promoter`, you can look up the sales data in `sales.sales` by matching the sales with the promoter. Then, using the `sales.model` column, you can find information about the relevant model in the `model` table. However, when I do

```
SELECT 
    promo.ID,
    promo.Branch,
    promo.Promoter,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sales.brand = 'TEST' AND sales.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' AND promo.branch = sales.branch THEN 1 END) AS Actual, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sales.brand = 'TEST' AND sales.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' AND promo.branch = sales.branch AND model.SizeRange = 'Small' THEN 1 END) AS SmallActual 
FROM sales.promo
    LEFT JOIN sales.sales ON promo.promoter = sales.promoter
    LEFT JOIN sales.model ON sales.model = model.model
GROUP BY promo.ID 
ORDER BY promo.ID ASC;
```

it ends up inflating the values in the Actual and SmallActual column by a seemingly random number. How can I fix this?

Searching online, I've seen people talk about 'table aggregation' and whatnot to fix it, but I don't understand how that is supposed to work. Does anyone know what's going wrong here? Thanks!

==========

Edit: Here are my tables with some sample data:

**Promoter table:**

| ID | Branch | Promoter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample | John Smith |

**Sales table:**

| ID | Promoter | Dealer | Branch | Brand | Model | DateSold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | Challenger | Sample | TEST | C123 | 2023-02-25 |

**Model Table:**

| ID | Model | Brand | SizeRange | SalesRangeCategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C123 | TEST | Small | Entry Level |

**Expected output:**

| ID | Branch | Promoter | Actual | SmallActual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample | John Smith | 91 | 26 |

**Actual output:**

| ID | Branch | Promoter | Actual | SmallActual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample | John Smith | 106 | 39 |

Comment: Show your tables

Comment: `LEFT JOIN sales.model ON sales.model = model.model` is probably joining on multiple records that match `sales.model = model.model`, which will cause more records to be returned. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76616932/edit) to show your DB schema, along with sample data and expected and actual results.

Comment: I've updated it with the expected output and all, but the tables break after I press save even though they worked fine in the edit screen.

Comment: OK, tables have been fixed.

Comment: You could skip the `COUNT` and`GROUP BY` parts to inspect the data

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with your data. The additional join should join the sale's model. This cannot lead to a higher sales count, unless there are two rows in the models table for the same model.

You should fix your data model to ensure data integrity:

The sales table must not contain `promoter`, but the `promoter.id`. And it must not contain `model`, but the `model.id`. E.g.

```
create table sales
(
  id           int auto_increment primary key,
  promoter_id  int,
  model_id     int,
  ...,
  constraint fk_sales_promo foreign key (promoter_id) references promo(id)
  constraint fk_sales_model foreign key (model_id) references model(id)
);
```

The same should apply for other entities, like dealers, branches and brands.

And make sure your tables contain the appropriate unique constraints:

- A model in the model table must be unique.
- A promoter in the promo table must be unique.
- A sale in the sales table may also have to be unique.

This would look like this:

```
create table promo
(
  ...,
  unique(promoter)
);

create table model
(
  ...,
  unique(model)
);

create table sales
(
  ...,
  unique(promoter_id, dealer_id, branch_id, brand_id, model_id, datesold)
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to quickly replace the promoter names with the ID? I made model.model the ID since that had unique values using VARCHAR, but I'm not sure how I'd deal with promoters. The promoters in the promo table aren't unique -- neither are the branches, as multiple staff can work at the same branch and vice versa.

Comment: OK, fixing the model table ended up making everything work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use right formatting style. It makes your code readable and more comfortable for work.

What about group by operator. You can't use columns in **select** block without using them in grouping and without some aggregation function.

In your task you can make subquery like this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    COUNT(
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.brand = 'TEST' 
             AND t2.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' 
             AND t1.branch = t2.branch 
            THEN 1 
        END
    ) AS Actual, 
    COUNT(
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.brand = 'TEST' 
             AND t2.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' 
             AND t1.branch = t2.branch 
             AND t3.SizeRange = 'Small' 
            THEN 1 
        END
    ) AS SmallActual 
FROM sales.promo t1
LEFT JOIN sales.sales t2 
ON t1.promoter = t2.promoter
LEFT JOIN sales.model t3
ON t2.model = t3.model
GROUP BY t1.ID 
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;
```

Do not forget table aliases. And if you want to add **Branch**, **Promoter** just use another join. Like this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.Promoter,
    t1.Branch,
    t2.*
FROM sales.promo t1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t1.ID,
        COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN t2.brand = 'TEST' 
                 AND t2.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' 
                 AND t1.branch = t2.branch 
                THEN 1 
            END
        ) AS Actual, 
        COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN t2.brand = 'TEST' 
                 AND t2.datesold BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' 
                 AND t1.branch = t2.branch 
                 AND t3.SizeRange = 'Small' 
                THEN 1 
            END
        ) AS SmallActual 
    FROM sales.promo t1
    LEFT JOIN sales.sales t2 
    ON t1.promoter = t2.promoter
    LEFT JOIN sales.model t3
    ON t2.model = t3.model
    GROUP BY t1.ID 
) t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but it just returns the same values. Are there any advantages to using table aliases?

Comment: The purpose of alias names is to get queries more readable. Yours do the opposite, because you have chosen arbitrary alias names that don't relate to the tables. Always use mnemonic alias names, e.g. p for promo, s for sales, m for model.